# Synonym [maintenance] -> [aircraft-maintenance]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, burninate-tag

Two tags currently exist for what seems the same purpose, with 10 and 45 questions, respectively.

I propose we keep [aircraft-maintenance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-maintenance) and make [maintenance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) a synonym, or just burninate it entirely.

Comment: Why keep aircraft-maintenance instead of maintenance?

Comment: @raptortech97 I posted an answer as to why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few question already (and likely could be more) regarding runway maintenance.  In the future we could see things regarding NDB, VOR or other radio maintenance. Or ILS and glide scope....  Perhaps even GPS, so long as it relates to aviation.

Point being, there are a lot of systems being maintained that are not aircraft.  I say we leave the tags separate.

Answer (score 3):

I think [aircraft-maintenance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-maintenance) should be the main tag - here's why:

We already have a lot of [`[aircraft-*]`](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-*) tags.

> [image]

Albeit 1 or 2 could do with burninating.

Comment: Can I ask why this is posted as an image? It'd be nice to be able to click some of those links

Comment: Purely because I could screengrab it 100x faster. Click the link I wrote `aircraft-*` on ;) From there you can see the tags on the right.

Comment: Oooh, fancy! :)

Answer (score 1):

I propose we keep [maintenance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) and make [aircraft-maintenance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-maintenance) a synonym instead. The former one is shorter.

Comment: Are there perhaps cases where we would be talking about maintenance of something other than an aircraft (runway maintenance perhaps)? I guess more to the point is it likely that will be a significant enough number of questions that we might not want [tag:maintenance] to point specifically at aircraft maintenance? (I'm inclined to think "no", and to make the synonym as suggested here.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend keeping the one with more questions (currently and by far [[aircraft-maintenance]](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-maintenance))